# using fn:replace and escaping special characters in jstl

Tags: html, replace, jstl

I've got a string of html code with some additional tags inside.  I need to get rid of the additional tags, but can't use fn:escapeXML because that would make the string no longer usable as html.

Example:
The value of "newLink" is set as:

`<a href="This is a <span class="help">test</span>">This is a <span class="help">test</span></a>`

How can I use fn:replace (or some other jstl coding) to get rid of the inner tags?

This is what I've managed so far.  Unfortunately, the last doesn't seem to match the empty tags.

`<c:set var="displayValue">${fn:replace(pnxItem, 'span class=\"searchword\"', '')}</c:set>
<c:set var="displayValue">${fn:replace(displayValue, '/span', '')}</c:set>
<c:set var="displayValue">${fn:replace(displayValue, '&gt;<', '')}</c:set>
<c:set var="displayValue">${fn:replace(displayValue, '<>', '')}</c:set>`

Comment: I have a hard time in understanding why `fn:escapeXml()` can't be used. I think it's easier if you just tell how exactly the desired result should look like.

Comment: It's not that it can't be used; it's that it's not matching the <> values.

Comment: You just want to parse and strip HTML instead of escape XML? Still, it's easier if you just tell how exactly the desired result of the given example should look like.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be nice if you could use a `regular expression`? Jstl's replace function does not take a regex as an argument, as you probably already know, judging from the approach you have taken.

Luckily it is quite easy to write your own functions. I always carry along a class named `StringFunctions`, consisting of `static` functions, to be used as a custom functions library that holds, for instance, a `removeTags` function.

```
 package com.whatever.viewhelpers;

 public class StringFunctions {  

    public static String removeTags(String s) {

        return s.replaceAll("\\<.*?>","");
    }

    // more functions ...
}
```

Now include this class in a tag library descriptor.

```
<taglib xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" version="2.0">  

    <tlib-version>1.0</tlib-version>  
    <short-name>myfn</short-name>  
    <uri>http://www.whatever.com/taglib/trlbt</uri>  

    <function>    
        <name>removeTags</name>    
        <function-class>
            com.whatever.viewhelpers.StringFunctions
        </function-class>    
        <function-signature>    
            String removeTags(java.lang.String)    
        </function-signature>  
    </function> 

    <!-- more functions -->

</taglib>
```

And use in jsp:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="myfn" uri="/WEB-INF/taglib/tlb.tld" %>
....

${myfn:removeTags( ... )}
```

I chose `myfn` as prefix but you are free to choose whatever suits you.

Not sure if the proposed regex fully satisfies your needs, but it demonstrates the principle of custom functions. You can do anything Java allows you to in there, you could even use [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) to get rid of the tags.